# Correlation of 2 categorical variables in linear model

Tags: r, regression, correlation, categorical-data

I have this dataframe with two categorical variables (Sex and Asian vs. European) and I need to fit a linear model to estimate the weight of a fetus given the day of the echography and these parameters, also I need to test if there is some correlation between Sex and Ethnicity.

1. I summarize the 2 categorical variables into 1 categorical variable with 4 levels, then I transform it in 3 dummies (ME = male european, FE and FA)

   ```
   fit <- lm(weight ~ 0 + days + days:ME + days:FE + days:MA) 
   summary(fit)

   Residuals:
         Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
   -0.305911 -0.074343  0.009762  0.081109  0.299959 

   Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   giorni     0.0113866  0.0001022 111.445  < 2e-16 ***
   giorni:ME  0.0006768  0.0001617   4.187 5.79e-05 ***
   giorni:FE -0.0001183  0.0001575  -0.752    0.454    
   giorni:MA  0.0007811  0.0001657   4.714 7.30e-06 ***
   ```

   However, I don't know how to test the interaction between Sex and Ethnic group
2. I don't touch the dataframe and call:

   ```
   fit <- lm(weight ~ 0  + days + days:sex +days:ethnic_gruop + giorni:sex:ethnic_gruop)

   > summary(fit)

   Residuals:
         Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
   -0.305911 -0.074343  0.009762  0.081109  0.299959 

   Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   days                   1.217e-02  1.305e-04  93.259  < 2e-16 ***
   days:sex0             -7.811e-04  1.657e-04  -4.714  7.3e-06 ***
   days:sex1                    NA         NA      NA       NA    
   days:group1           -1.184e-04  1.575e-04  -0.752    0.454    
   days:sex1:gropu1       1.408e-05  2.398e-04   0.059    0.953    
   ---
   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
   ```

   And I don't get the estimate of one coefficient...

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the estimate because two variables are perfectly collinear. Your reference (baseline) variable belongs to `group 0` and `sex0` so estimation of `days:sex0` is perfectly collinear with your reference variable. Strangely enough you get `NA` with `days:sex1` coefficient. You should provide a data sample so we can see what went wrong with recoding.

So the age in days influences the weight differently depending on sex and ethnicity (2x2 variables).

People with `sex0` and `group0` form a baseline category with a corresponding `days` coeffient.

People with `sex1` and `group0` form a first contrast with a corresponding `days:sex1` coeffient.

People with `sex0` and `group1` form a second contrast with a corresponding `days:group1` coeffient.

People with `sex1` and `group1` form a third contrast with a corresponding `days:sex1:group1` coeffient.

There should obviously be only 4 coefficients but you have 5. Also I don't see any value in recoding variables as you did at point 1. in your question.